# Presented view controller hidden under navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, presentviewcontroller

I'm really new to iOS development, following some courses now to get into it. Goal is to fix a really old application that's been created by a former colleague at the start of 2011. I'm having this issue that I can't fix.

I want to present a ViewController showing a login screen. But when the ViewController is presented, it hides under the navigationController and statusbar. I also get this error:

**Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged**

Here's the code:

```
    Login *fvController = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [fvController setTitle:@"Login"];
    UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fvController];
    [fvController setKc:self];
    [self presentViewController:navCon animated:YES completion:nil];
    [fvController release];
    [navCon release];
    navCon = nil;
    fvController = nil;
```

Anyone who could help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

UIWindows have a rootViewController field pointing to the first view controller in your hierarchy. If you present a view controller from a controller outside this hierarchy weird things happen.

Check if your key window ([yourUIApplication keyWindow]) has this field set. If it is nil your entire hierarchy is detached and it needs a rehaul. If the window has a root view controller you can present your view from here while you restructure your hierarchy so that all views are eventually connected to the root.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for commenting! I don't exactly know where to do this. I've set my rootViewController in my AppDelegate like this:

`window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];`

You're right that there must be something wrong with the hierarchy. This app uses Xib's btw.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you are releasing your created instance of your ViewController, try to change code like this:

Declare your viewControllers under @implementation at the top of your viewController

```
@implementation yourViewController
{
   Login *fvController;
   UINavigationController *navCon;
}
```

Now change your code like this

```
fvController = [[Login alloc] initWithNibName:@"Login" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[fvController setTitle:@"Login"];
navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fvController];
[fvController setKc:self];
[self presentViewController:navCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And add your releasing objects to dealloc method

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
    [fvController release];
    [navCon release];
    navCon = nil;
    fvController = nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This actually isn't working. I get _Use of undeclared identifier_ errors at the dealloc method.

Comment: You are getting those errors because your viewControllers are not declared as global. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for commenting. These errors are gone now indeed. But I get _Local declaration of '' hides instance variable_ warnings now. Btw, I get a lot of these warnings throughout my project.

Comment: You are getting those errors because you are declaring again your variables that you have declared under implementation, or synthesised properties. So under the implementation you are declaring Login *fvController. But also in another method you are declaring again Login *fvController; while you can just type fvController.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! But it didn't solve the problem. The presented viewController is still hidden underneath the navigationController. I also still got this _Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged_ warning. Think it has more to do with setting the rootController from where this new viewController is being presented, like @JavierC states. But i can't figure out what that exactly means...

Comment: You are working with XIB and I have not worked with these layouts, but this function is not executed on your presented navigationController, you need to set it before you embed your vc in nc: [fvController setKc:self];